# Who hired the burglars of Bashere's tent in CoT prologue?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In [Wheel of Time Book 10, Crossroads of Twilight](https://a.co/d/hCayJSy) Prologue, [Davram Bashere](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Davram_Bashere)'s tent is robbed and [Deira Bashere](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Deira_Bashere) is injured fighting off the robbers. The burglars are then found dead.

Here is the [summary from the Fandom wiki](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Crossroads_of_Twilight/Prologue):

> Upon arriving in the camp, Bashere makes his way to his wife who has just survived an assassination attempt. The would-be killers are found dead just outside the camp. Bashere sets up a meeting with a man that arrived the day before.

Who hired them? Who killed them? If we don't know, is it known that we don't know (maybe from an interview with Robert Jordan or Brandon Sanderson)?